# Siddhi application unable to deploy siddhi app while running the worker

Tags: wso2, wso2-streaming-integrator

I am trying to deploy a siddhi application.

I have copied the .siddhi app to /wso2/worker/deployment/siddhi-files.

When I run the worker.sh file, I get the following error.

```
[2019-05-20 17:06:07,958] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.stream.processor.core.internal.StreamProcessorDeployer} - org.wso2.carbon.stream.processor.core.internal.exception.SiddhiAppDeploymentException: Siddhi App file name needs be identical with the name defined in the Siddhi App content org.wso2.carbon.stream.processor.core.internal.exception.SiddhiAppDeploymentException: org.wso2.carbon.stream.processor.core.internal.exception.SiddhiAppDeploymentException: Siddhi App file name needs be identical with the name defined in the Siddhi App content
        at org.wso2.carbon.stream.processor.core.internal.StreamProcessorDeployer.deploySiddhiQLFile(StreamProcessorDeployer.java:105)
        at org.wso2.carbon.stream.processor.core.internal.StreamProcessorDeployer.deploy(StreamProcessorDeployer.java:306)
        at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.DeploymentEngine.lambda$deployArtifacts$0(DeploymentEngine.java:291)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
        at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.DeploymentEngine.deployArtifacts(DeploymentEngine.java:282)
        at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.RepositoryScanner.sweep(RepositoryScanner.java:112)
        at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.RepositoryScanner.scan(RepositoryScanner.java:68)
        at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.DeploymentEngine.start(DeploymentEngine.java:121)
        at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.DeploymentEngineListenerComponent.onAllRequiredCapabilitiesAvailable(DeploymentEngineListenerComponent.java:216)
        at org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupComponentManager.lambda$notifySatisfiableComponents$7(StartupComponentManager.java:266)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
        at org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupComponentManager.notifySatisfiableComponents(StartupComponentManager.java:252)
        at org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupOrderResolver$1.run(StartupOrderResolver.java:204)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.stream.processor.core.internal.exception.SiddhiAppDeploymentException: Siddhi App file name needs be identical with the name defined in the Siddhi App content
        at org.wso2.carbon.stream.processor.core.internal.StreamProcessorDeployer.deploySiddhiQLFile(StreamProcessorDeployer.java:96)
        ... 14 more
```

It is not clear as to where the 'Siddhi App Content' is to be modified.
Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

The file name and the name defined in

```
@App:name('....')
```

annotation in the siddhi file should be the same.